# how to pass form data from fancybox iframe to parent form

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I'm using fancybox inside a post form fieldset to display a form which contains checkbox options.
I would like to pass the data from the iframe checkbox form to the parent form to do DB query.

How I can achieve such thing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this :

```
var iframeValue = $("iframeText").val();
$(parent).find("parentElementId").val(iframeValue);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I will try this one.
could you please provide the complete code snippet?

Comment: @user1537701, its a sample that how could you transfer the iframe element value to its parent.

Comment: this goes inside the onclosed fancybox hook?

Comment: I guess this should be in "onCleanup"